# angularjs ng-repeat on two levels but just one output

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a big object that looks something like this :

```
scope.marketplaces = {

    first_example : { ... },
    second_example : { ... },

    ...

};
```

What I'm trying to do is loop through the big object like this :

```
<section>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in marketplaces"></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

And inside the loop, loop again each object, but instead of appending to DOM something like :

```
<li> ... first level loop ...

    <li> ... second level loop ... </li>
</li>
```

I would like to have just one `<li></li>` despite the level I'm looping through. The reason why I want it like that is because I need the `key` from the first loop to be referenced down the level loops and still have just one `li`.

I've read that `ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText"` could do what I want but I'm not sure if in the filter expression I can dynamically specify the `key` or something else that is needed instead of `searchText` ( I guess that is an already know property of the object ).

So my question is, can I achieve what I just explained with the `filter` or is there another way of doing it ?

Comment: Can you write example even not working html markup what you would like to have?

Comment: sounds like you want to flatten your data before passing it into the controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I've understood question: you would like to have one ngRepeat on a nested object. So kind of linearize object.

First approach would be to create filter:

```
app.filter('linear', function() {
  return function(value) {
    var result = {};
    for(var key in value) {
      for(var cKey in value[key]) {
        result[key+'_'+cKey] = value[key][cKey];
      }      
    }
    return result;
  };
});
```

and in thml:

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in marketplaces | linear">
          {{key}}: {{value}}
</li>
```

**But unfortunally** AngularJS have problems when in filter you create new elements. You can have error message in console kind of:

```
10 $digest iterations reached
```

Without hacks with `$$hash` you can't achieve that functionality for now *(Please correct me if I am wrong)*.

So I think for now the solution would be to watch 'marketplaces' in controller and create new object using same code as in controller that use in ngRepeat:

```
$scope.$watch('marketplaces', function(value) {
    var result = {};
    for(var key in value) {
      for(var cKey in value[key]) {
        result[key+'_'+cKey] = value[key][cKey];
      }      
    }
    $scope.linearMarketplaces = result;

  }, true);
```

And in HTML:

```
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in linearMarketplaces">
      {{key}}: {{value}}
    </li>
```

Plunker with both solutions: http://plnkr.co/edit/pYWFhqSqKAa9gpzek77P?p=preview

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do, some kind of recursive iteration that flattens the result to an single `li` rather than nested `li`'s. So what you're saying is that I'd better use `$watch` instead of a filter ? Could you have a short example of how could I do it in a directive, in the link function ? Because I already have the directives set up.

Comment: Also, besides the angular core do I have to include any extra angular library ? Like the sanitize ?

Comment: Also, if I change my filter function to something like this : `app.filter('linear', function() {
  return function(value) {
       var result = [];

      for(var key in value) {
        
        for(var cKey in value[key]) {
           result.push({ Item : value[key][cKey], Marketplace : key });
         };      
      };

      return result;
    };
});` I get the error that I got once before with the `10$digest` iterations reached ...

Comment: @Roland I've described why you get error with "10 $digest". And updated my answer with solution how to do with $watch. And also updated plunker with both solution. Unfortunally I do not see generic way how to achieve then (except global service/$rootScope functions to linearise objects) like some directive.