# ng-repeat of hierarchy displayed as list

Tags: list, tree, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS, but I am really enjoying working with it so far. I have used AngularJS's ng-repeat to create tree structures in HTML where the children of a node a placed ***within*** a node's markup, like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    I am the parent node.
    <div class="child">
        I am a child node.
        <div class="child">
            I am a grandchild.
            etc...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but what I'd like to do instead is use the same data (a tree) to make some markup like this:

```
<div class="parent">I am the parent</div>
<div class="child">I am a child</div>
<div class="child">I am a grandchild</div>
<div class="child">I am a great-grandchild</div>
etc....
```

I.e., a list. The only way I have come up with to do this is by creating a new method on my container object called visibleDescendants, which makes an array and looks a lot like this:

```
this.visibleDescendants = function(a) {
  if (!a) a = [];
  if (this.selected()) {
    a.push(this);
    if (this.hasChildren()) {
      this.children().forEach(function(child) {
        if (child.selected()) {
          a = child.visibleDescendants(a);
        }
      });
    }
  }
  return a;
};
```

and then setting up the controller/template like this:

```
$scope.visibleDescendants = $scope.container.visibleDescendants();
<div ng-repeat="column in visibleDescendants">...</div>
```

and then every time one of the nodes is set to `selected(false)`, I reset $scope.visibleDescendants.

That doesn't seem very efficient, and not very idiomatic, either, compared to other stuff I've been reading about/doing with AngularJS. I would like to be able to figure out a way to do this more declaratively in the template partial instead. Please help!

Comment: Not so long ago I've answered simillar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921992/angularjs-ng-repeat-on-two-levels-but-just-one-output/14922966#14922966 hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think what I'm really trying to do is a matter of presentation and shouldn't affect the markup. In other words, the data and the markup ought to match structurally/semantically; only the CSS should change its appearance.

That said, I don't think it's wise to mess with restructuring the data for presentation purposes.